# NodeJS: How to continuously write to a CSV file?

Tags: node.js, csv, stream

I am trying to use http://www.adaltas.com/projects/node-csv/

I have a nested array of information

```
var info = [["foo", "bar"], ["hello", "world"]]
info.forEach(function(line) {
  csv.from(line).to(fs.createWriteStream(path))
})
```

This does not work as it simply replaces the file everytime. I am guessing I need to turn the nested array into some sort of readable stream which I then pipe into the writeStream?

I am not too familiar with streaming programming and am a little stuck.

EDIT: I am open to any csv library. I just need a way to write lines into a csv format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add to append to the file need to pass the [append flag](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback) to `fs.createWriteStream` otherwise your file will be truncated when you open it. Example of how to set to append below:

```
var info = [["foo", "bar"], ["hello", "world"]]
info.forEach(function(line) {
  csv.from(line).to(fs.createWriteStream(path, {flags: 'a'}))
})
```